# How to get variables in one define from another?

Tags: puppet

Suppose, the following Puppet code:

```
define apache::base($pkgver = '2.4.10') {
    $apache_ver = $pkgver
    ...
}
define apache::vhost($instance) {
    ...
    $apache_ver = getvar(......)
}

apache::base{ "static-files":}
apache::base{ "dynamic": pkgver => '2.4.8' }
apache::vhost{ "static.example.com": instance => "static-files"}
```

How can the code in `apache::vhost` refer to `$pkgver` (parameter) or `$apache_ver` (variable) in the corresponding `apache::base`?

Our stdlib is too old (and our Puppet is still 2.7.x) and does not have `getparam()`. `getvar()` ought to be able to do it -- but how? What is the full name of the variable in this case?

I tried `getvar("apache::base[$instance]::apache_ver")` and `getvar("apache::base::$instance::apache_ver")` to no avail -- getvar returns an empty string... What's the right method?

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

To get at such a value, you would have to refer to an *instance* of your defined type, e.g.

```
Apache::Vhost['main-site']::server_alias
```

Such a thing is not implemented, though.

You need to restructure your model. In your module, `apache::vhost` cannot be independent of `apache::base`. Instead, you will want to hand a resource hash to `apache::base` so that it can declare the vhosts itself.

```
define apache::base($pkgver = '2.4.10', $vhosts = {}) {
  $apache_ver = $pkgver
  ...
  create_resources('apache::vhost', $vhosts, { instance => $title })
}
```

And use it like

```
apache::base{ "static-files":
  vhosts => {
    "static.example.com" => { 
      # attributes for Apache::Vhost["static.example.com"] go here
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: The "such a thing is not implemented" is the most valuable part of your answer, Felix. Thank you... But are you sure? Is not `getvar()` supposed to do just that -- if invoked properly?

Comment: To be more specific: The Puppet language has no construct that allows this kind of cross-reference. There are parser functions that *will* allow you to [inspect the catalog during build](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/f820bb156038f638d8e488286d0c2b92c5636925/lib/puppet/parser/functions/ensure_resource.rb#L38), but using them is dangerous because their result is evaluation order dependent (i.e., they are not reliable).

Comment: Thanks for the warning -- I will ensure the order base->vhost. But, still, what is the proper way to refer to a particular instance of apache::base with `getvar()`?

Comment: `getvar` cannot as far as I know. You would need to build a custom function, basically a variation on [defined_with_params](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/master/lib/puppet/parser/functions/defined_with_params.rb) but again: **This is very prone for latent errors and should be avoided if possible in any way**.

Comment: Wait, is not that the very _purpose_ of `getvar()`?..

Comment: No. `getvar` is basically just a wrapper for the `lookupvar` scope method. It cannot access a define's parameters or declared variables because defined types don't spawn namespaces for their instances. Looking up *class* parameters is no problem, but with defines, it won't work.